# C++ eliminating odd or even numbers

Tags: c++

I'm doing an exercise where it is asking to eliminate any number divisible by 5 that ends up as a whole number. So instead of :

```
If (num == 5 || num == 10) 
    continue;
```

Is there some way to tell the computer if it is divisible by 5 don't output it or if it is odd or even don't output the number? Please try to leave answers at a novice level I am just starting to program.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool isDivisibleBy5 = n % 5 == 0;
```

where `n` is your number. For odd numbers,

```
bool isOdd = n % 2; // evaluates to 0 if even, so false
```

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator % gives you the remainder of a division, so you can just check if that is zero

```
num % 5 == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A number is divisible by 5 with if the modulus, namely, `operator%` returns 0.

You can do:

```
if (n % 5 == 0) {
  //number is divisible by 5
}
else {
  //not divisible by 5
}
```

Comment: Does the % mean it is dividing num by 5? And also does 0 mean even?

Comment: % is the operator that gives you the remainder of dividing. So that means that the operation says: "if the remainder of n divided by 5 is 0..."

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num % 5 == 0)
    continue;
```

Will only continue on 5, 10, 15...